# Flutter: вывод данных из sqlite из категории и подкатегории

Tags: sqlite, flutter

База данных подключена. Все работает, но я не понимаю как заставить выводить данные по щелчку категории:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/article.dart';

import '../database_provider.dart';

class HomeTab extends StatefulWidget {
  final DatabaseProvider databaseProvider;

  HomeTab({this.databaseProvider});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return HomeTabState();
  }
}

class HomeTabState extends State<HomeTab> {
  List<MyTile> tiles = [];

  @override 
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.wait([
      widget.databaseProvider.getMeetingGamesMl(),
      widget.databaseProvider.getMeetingGamesSr(),
      widget.databaseProvider.getMeetingGamesSt(),
      widget.databaseProvider.getSplochenieGamesMl(),
      widget.databaseProvider.getSplochenieGamesSr(),
      widget.databaseProvider.getSplochenieGamesSt(),
      widget.databaseProvider.getDoverieGamesMl(),
      widget.databaseProvider.getDoverieGamesSr(),
      widget.databaseProvider.getDoverieGamesSt(),
      widget.databaseProvider.getLiderGamesMl(),
      widget.databaseProvider.getLiderGamesSr(),
      widget.databaseProvider.getLiderGamesSr(),
      widget.databaseProvider.igriNaVzaimodeistvie(),
      widget.databaseProvider.igriNaVoobrazenie(),
      widget.databaseProvider.igriVPomeshenii(),
      widget.databaseProvider.igriDlyStanchii(),
      widget.databaseProvider.igriPytiminutki(),
      widget.databaseProvider.igriVAvtobuse(),
      widget.databaseProvider.podviznieIgri(),
      widget.databaseProvider.igriRozigrishi(),
      widget.databaseProvider.igrodiskoteka(),
      widget.databaseProvider.igriKonkursi(),
      widget.databaseProvider.igriSBall(),
      widget.databaseProvider.igriSZalom(),
      widget.databaseProvider.igriVVode(),
      widget.databaseProvider.danetki()
    ]).then((v) => _fillTiles(v));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return StuffInTiles(tiles[index]);
          },
          itemCount: tiles.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _fillTiles(List<List<Article>> articlesList) {
    var index = 0;
    tiles = [
      MyTile(
        'ИГРЫ НА ЗНАКОМСТВА',
        children: [
          MyTile('Младший | 7-10 лет', articles: articlesList[index++]),
          MyTile('Средний | 10 - 12 лет', articles: articlesList[index++]),
          MyTile('Старший | 13-16 лет', articles: articlesList[index++]),
        ],
      ),
      new MyTile(
        'ИГРЫ НА СПЛОЧЕНИЕ',
        children: <MyTile>[
          new MyTile('Младший | 7-10 лет', articles: articlesList[index++]),
          new MyTile('Средний | 10 - 12 лет', articles: articlesList[index++]),
          new MyTile('Старший | 13-16 лет', articles: articlesList[index++]),
        ],
      ),
      new MyTile(
        'ИГРЫ НА ДОВЕРИЕ',
        children: <MyTile>[
          new MyTile('Младший', articles: articlesList[index++]),
          new MyTile('Средний', articles: articlesList[index++]),
          new MyTile('Старший', articles: articlesList[index++]),
        ],
      ),
      new MyTile(
        'ИГРЫ НА ВЫЯВЛЕНИЕ ЛИДЕРА',
        children: <MyTile>[
          new MyTile('Младший | 7-10 лет', articles: articlesList[index++]),
          new MyTile('Средний | 10 - 12 лет', articles: articlesList[index++]),
          new MyTile('Старший | 13-16 лет', articles: articlesList[index++]),
        ],
      ),
      new MyTile('ИГРЫ НА ВЗАИМОДЕЙСТВИЕ', articles: articlesList[index++]),
      new MyTile('ИГРЫ НА ВООБРАЖЕНИЕ', articles: articlesList[index++]),
      new MyTile('ИГРЫ В ПОМЕЩЕНИИ', articles: articlesList[index++]),
      new MyTile('ИГРЫ ДЛЯ СТАНЦИИ', articles: articlesList[index++]),
      new MyTile('ИГРЫ ПЯТИМУТКИ', articles: articlesList[index++]),
      new MyTile('ИГРЫ В АВТОБУСЕ', articles: articlesList[index++]),
      new MyTile('ПОДВИЖНЫЕ ИГРЫ', articles: articlesList[index++]),
      new MyTile('ИГРЫ-РОЗЫГРЫШИ', articles: articlesList[index++]),
      new MyTile('ИГРОДИСКОТЕКА', articles: articlesList[index++]),
      new MyTile('ИГРЫ-КОНКУРСЫ', articles: articlesList[index++]),
      new MyTile('ИГРЫ С МЯЧОМ', articles: articlesList[index++]),
      new MyTile('ИГРЫ С ЗАЛОМ', articles: articlesList[index++]),
      new MyTile('ИГРЫ В ВОДЕ', articles: articlesList[index++]),
      new MyTile('ДАНЕТКИ', articles: articlesList[index++]),
    ];
    setState(() {});
  }
}

class StuffInTiles extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyTile myTile;

  StuffInTiles(this.myTile);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return buildTiles(myTile);
  }

  Widget buildTiles(MyTile v) {
    if (v.children.isEmpty)
      return new ListTile(
          dense: true,
          enabled: true,
          isThreeLine: false,
          onLongPress: () => print("long press"),
          onTap: () => print("tap"),
          selected: false,
          trailing: new Text("+"),
          title: new Text(v.title));

    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: new PageStorageKey<int>(3),
      title: new Text(v.title),
      children: v.children.map(buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }
}

class MyTile {
  String title;
  List<Article> articles;
  List<MyTile> children;

  MyTile(this.title, {this.children = const <MyTile>[], this.articles});
}

List<MyTile> listOfTiles = <MyTile>[
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРЫ НА ЗНАКОМСТВА',
    children: <MyTile>[
      new MyTile('Младший | 7-10 лет'),
      new MyTile('Средний | 10 - 12 лет'),
      new MyTile('Старший | 13-16 лет'),
    ],
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРЫ НА СПЛОЧЕНИЕ',
    children: <MyTile>[
      new MyTile('Младший | 7-10 лет'),
      new MyTile('Средний | 10 - 12 лет'),
      new MyTile('Старший | 13-16 лет'),
    ],
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРЫ НА ДОВЕРИЕ',
    children: <MyTile>[
      new MyTile('Младший | 7-10 лет'),
      new MyTile('Средний | 10 - 12 лет'),
      new MyTile('Старший | 13-16 лет'),
    ],
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРЫ НА ВЫЯВЛЕНИЕ ЛИДЕРА',
    children: <MyTile>[
      new MyTile('Младший | 7-10 лет'),
      new MyTile('Средний | 10 - 12 лет'),
      new MyTile('Старший | 13-16 лет'),
    ],
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРЫ НА ВЗАИМОДЕЙСТВИЕ',
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРЫ НА ВООБРАЖЕНИЕ',
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРЫ В ПОМЕЩЕНИИ',
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРЫ ДЛЯ СТАНЦИИ',
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРЫ ПЯТИМИНУТКИ',
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРЫ В АВТОБУСЕ',
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ПОДВИЖНЫЕ ИГРЫ',
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРЫ-РОЗЫГРЫШИ',
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРОДИСКОТЕКА',
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРЫ-КОНКУРСЫ',
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРЫ С МЯЧОМ',
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРЫ С ЗАЛОМ',
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ИГРЫ В ВОДЕ',
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'ДАНЕТКИ',
  ),
];
```

Понимаю, что дело в этом, но как отредактировать код, чтобы при нажатии выходила активити с категорией?

```
Widget buildTiles(MyTile v) {
    if (v.children.isEmpty)
      return new ListTile(
          dense: true,
          enabled: true,
          isThreeLine: false,
          onLongPress: () => print("long press"),
          onTap: () => print("tap"),
          selected: false,
          trailing: new Text("+"),
          title: new Text(v.title));
```

Вот скрипт, который реализует аналогичное напрямую:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/article.dart';

import '../database_provider.dart';

class FireTab extends StatefulWidget {
  final DatabaseProvider databaseProvider;

  FireTab({this.databaseProvider});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {

    return FireTabState();
  }
}

class FireTabState extends State<FireTab> {
  List<Article> articles = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.databaseProvider
        .getLiderGamesSr()
        .then((articles) => _onArticlesLoaded(articles));

  }

  void _onArticlesLoaded(List<Article> articles) {
    setState(() {

      this.articles = articles;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: articles.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
          title: Text(articles[index].title),
            onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
                      appBar:AppBar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                          title: Text(articles[index].title)),

                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      body: Text(articles[index].text),
                    )));
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Поподробнее расскажите что должно получиться? Формулировка: `чтобы при нажатии выходила активити с категорией?`, не понятна. Что за активити? Куда выходила?

Comment: Я хочу реализовать функцию справочника, когда пользователь видит вкладку "игры в автобусе" - нажимает на нее и попадает на список игр. Выбирает, например, заголовок "подсчитай березы" и попадает на полное описание игры. 

На данный момент  отслеживается только нажатие, но  как реализовать код, который  сначала выводит список статей, а потом целую статью - я не могу придумать.

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь правильно понял:

```
onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DescriptionScreen(v))),

class DescriptionScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyTile myTile;

  DescriptionScreen(this.myTile);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(myTile.title),
      ),
      body: Container(child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: myTile.children.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Column(children: [Text(myTile.articles[index]...)]);
          },
      ))
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: Незнаю как в комментарии приклеплять изображения, только за счет коротких ссылок. Аргумент имеет неизвестный тип в 1 случае и 2 аргумент имеет строковое значение. То есть title передается в виде цифер получается? О_О
https://prnt.sc/s2t7nl https://prnt.sc/s2t9t2

Comment: `Widget buildTiles(BuildContext context, MyTile v) {...}`, `return buildTiles(context, myTile);`

Comment: @Boglik для второго случая поставе поле после точки, например `myTile.articles[index].count` т.е. вместо count у вас будет что-то свое. `То есть title передается в виде цифер получается?` нет, у вас список, с помощью цифры мы выбираем элемент из списка. _Это вообще ваш код? Складывается ощущение что вы в нем ничего не понимаете..._